# Question about group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can someone explain what a group action is in layman terms? I know what a group is, but I can't understand what a group action, even after doing a lot of Google searches.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action

Comment: I've read it alot, but I still don't understand it. Could you give an intuition behind the idea?

Comment: I tried shorting it down and dumbing it down a bit. It might not be entirely technical correct but I hope it shows the most important ideas.

Comment: Consider the rotational symmetry group $G$ of a cube. The group $G$ **acts** on the set $V$ of vertices, it acts on the set $E$ of edges, it acts on the set $F$ of faces, and it acts on the set $D$ of diagonals (line segments joining opposite vertices). Each action can be thought of as  a way of interpreting elements of $G$ as a permutation of the set, i.e. as a map (elements of $G$) $\to$ (permutations of $X$), where $X=V,E,F,D$. Composition of rotations must correspond to composition of permutations, so the four maps $G\to{\rm Perm}(X)$ must be group homomorphisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We associate each group element $g$ with an own function $f_g$. Each such function takes elements from a set $X$ and puts back something from the same set.

Two particular things must be fulfilled for the set of functions:

1. **Identity:** The function corresponding to the identity element of the group must do $x\to x, \forall x\in X$
2. **Compatibility** requires that $f_{ab} = f_a \circ f_b$. That is group operation "translates" to function composition for the group action. $f_{ab}(x) = f_a(f_b(x))$

Comment: I have nothing against this answer, but I'm wondering if @mathtm really did any search on their own. I'm failing to see what insight this answer provides that Wikipedia doesn't and yet, they accepted this answer.

Comment: @Ennar : Maybe the person asking the question was intimidated by the sheer amount and the language on wikipedia and that hindered learning. It would not surprise me if the language of higher algebra with all it's unnecessarily complicated words scares students to fail to learn.

Comment: What is absorbed by you when reading something may not be the same as what is absorbed by someone used to read stuff written in another style using different words.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, I just voiced what I think is a legit concern given that OP is a relatively new user.

Comment: That much of higher algebra uses a language that puts off people like the OP from wanting / being able to absorb the material is more of a concern imo.

Comment: That can be said about any area that uses precise language that majority of the experts agreed upon. In the same manner, I could say that not knowing any Chinese puts me off from wanting to live in China, but that's not really the problem of Chinese people, but my personal.

Comment: It depends on which view you decide to put the focus on. For whom is it important? You argue from the viewpoint of an expert and neither a teacher or a learner. It is quite likely that it looks different from a teachers, an employers or an investors view. There is also a difference between the language as used by experts and the language used in teaching the basics of a subject. Often you would do better teaching or learning if being introduced do the new words gradually *after* having had the concepts explained. Otherwise there's a fair chance no learning will occur.

Comment: Again, I'm not disagreeing with you, I just found your previous comment vague. You say it yourself, the language that is used can be perceived too advanced, appropriate or too informal, depending on listener/reader. But this discussion is getting off-topic and I'm not seeing the point of continuing it. I'll just rephrase my previous comments: it might be that you are right, and that the language used at the wiki article was too advanced for OP, but it might be that OP didn't really put real effort of reading through material. Whatever the case, I'm not finding any issue with the said article.

Comment: If the goal is for learning to happen then I don't see how a discussion about what works or not would be off topic.

Comment: Both the question and this answer are not about learning, they are about group actions. Topic of language used for teaching is hardly relevant. What is relevant is similarity of this answer with what is written in Wikipedia in a sense that I have doubts that OP actually read what is written there, while claiming that they did. That was my point. Your point was that the language you used might be more understandable to OP. Nothing else needs to be said here.

Comment: @Ennar : It is mentioned in the question that the asker was unable to make sense of any source he might have found, **not** that he could **not** find any. That is the point when the question became one about learning and the language used in teaching.

Comment: First of all, I never said that they couldn't find source, I questioned whether real effort was put into understanding what was found. Secondly, Google search is not a substitute for teaching material and was never meant to be one. It is only your interpretation that this is due to language, not confirmed by OP, and not shared nor dismissed by me. I'm not sure why you are making philosophical stand here and I'm surely failing to see how exactly what you write is a big improvement, if any at all, compared to what can be found in any source on the topic.

Comment: How little inertia there is to digest a source is still a measure of the quality of the source, at least for any learning purpose, maybe not so much for just reviewing material already learned though.

Answer (score 7):

One of the common ways that groups appear in mathematics is as symmetry groups.

This is very common in geometry. For example, the symmetries of a regular $n$-gon form a group isomorphic to the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) of order $2n$. Also, the symmetries of a regular tetrahedron form a group isomorphic to the symmetric group on 4 elements, which has order $4!=24$. More generally the symmetries of a regular $n$-simplex in $n$-dimensional space form a group isomorphic to the symmetric group on $n+1$ elements, which has order $(n+1)!$.

This is also common in other branches of mathematics. For example, in Galois theory, the symmetries of the roots of a polynomial that are induced by automorphisms of the splitting field form the Galois group of that polynomial (which, historically, was the very first kind of group explicitly noticed by mathematicians; although one might argue that the 17 [wallpaper groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group) were noticed earlier by medieval artisans).

From a mathematical historical perspective, groups of symmetries appeared before abstract groups. Once the concept of a group is abstracted, then of course the power of algebra kicks in, and we can make great strides in understanding group theory. Nonetheless, many of the practical applications of groups are still rooted in their origins as groups of symmetries.

So, how can one connect the original notion of symmetry groups with the abstract notion of a group?

The answer is: with the concept of a group action. When you are given a group $G$ and a mathematical object $X$ (like a tetrahedron, or the set of roots of a polynomial, or any mathematical object whatsoever), you can ask questions like:

- Is this group $G$ the group of symmetries of $X$?

This rather informal question can be formalized by rewording it as:

- Is there an isomorphism between $G$ and the group of symmetries of $X$?

As is often fruitful, it might be useful to broaden one's interest from isomorphisms to homomorphisms:

- Is there a homomorphism from $G$ to the group of symmetries of $X$?

And now one is ready for the definition:

- An action of a group $G$ on a mathematical object $X$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to the group of symmetries of $X$.

If this definition does not sound familiar, go compare it to whatever definition you like, such as the definitions in other answers here. You will find that these definitions are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first understand endofunction composition and invertible endofunctions. Suppose we have a set $X$ and a family $F$ of endofunctions $f:X\to X$. Given two such functions, $f_1, f_2\in F$ the composition $f_3$ is given by $f_3(x) := f_1(f_2(x))$. We require that the composition of endofunctions in the family is also in the family. An invertible endofunction $f_1$ is such that there is an inverse endofunction $f_2$ such that $f_2(f_1(x)) = f_1(f_2(x)) = x$ for all $x\in X$. We require that the inverse of any endofunction in the family is also in the family. By the definition of a group, the family $F$ is a group because composition is associative and so on.

Now, suppose we have an abstract group $G$ and a mapping $\phi:G\to F$ that is compatible between the group operation and endofunction composition. That is, if $\;\phi(g_1)=f_1,\;\phi(g_2)=f_2\;$ and $\phi(g_1g_2)=f_3,\;$ then $f_2(f_1(x))=f_3(x)$. We say that $\phi$ is a homomorphism of groups, but more specifically, in this case, it is a group $G$ acting (on the left) of the set $X$ via $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ where $\varphi(g,x)=\phi(g)(x)$. This idea of mapping an abstract group element to an endofunction is very common in applications of group theory to science. Often, an invertible endofunction is called a permutation and that is an alternative name for it.